# How to order strings format from database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have numbers like this: 666/2014, 01/2014, 1/2014, 02/2014, 125/2014, 06/2014 ...etc as  STRING named 'n_inscription' in database.
I want to retrieve those strings In ORDER from database

I used this:

```
$sql_students = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM `es_student_infos`
                            WHERE school_year='$school_year'
                            ORDER BY right(n_inscription, 4) * 1,
                            substring_index(n_inscription, '/', 1) * 1");
```

I get result like this:
01/2014, 
02/2014,
06/2014,
1/2014,
125/2014,
666/2014

and the result I'm looking for is like this:
01/2014,
1/2014,
02/2014,
06/2014,
125/2014,
666/2014

any suggestion please?

Comment: Are those month/year values and 125/2014 a typo?

Comment: no, The numbers I gave above are not dates.. those are students IDS. The first number represent the student ID and the second represent the school year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is probably to normalize the input so normal sorting does what you want it to do. For example, store the student number and year in two separate `INTEGER` columns and then `ORDER BY studentNumber ASC, inscriptionYear ASC`.

If that's absolutely not possible:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  es_student_infos
ORDER BY
  CAST(RIGHT(n_inscription, 4) AS UNSIGNED) ASC,
  CAST(LEFT(n_inscription, LOCATE('/', n_inscription) - 1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Link to fiddle demonstrating the solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5538/1/0

Comment: its still not working. the result i get with your query like this:
1/2014, 125/2014, 666/2014, 01/2014, 02/2014, 06/2014, 

and what i want is this order:
1/2014, 01/2014, 02/2014, 06/2014, 125/2014, 666/2014, 
OR
01/2014, 1/2014, 02/2014, 06/2014, 125/2014, 666/2014, 

because 01/2014 is the same as 1/2014 and 02/2014 is the same as 2/2014 as well, no difference between theme

Comment: @Mariem: it seems to work for me. I've added sorting per year and an SQL fiddle to demonstrate the solution. Is it still not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is change the type of n_inscription to date/datetime/timestamp and then use order by as default.

There's more advantages to use date fields like comparison and date calculations, so I suggest you do like this.

**EDIT: Change the order by collumn to school_year and not n_inscription:**

```
 SELECT * FROM `es_student_infos`
                            WHERE school_year='$school_year'
                            ORDER school_year
```

Comment: The numbers I gave above are not dates.. those are students ids, the first number represent the student ID and the second represent the school year